# Three.js moving the camera left and right side of the scene

Tags: three.js, camera, move

I am working on a three.js prototype in which a  3d model of the train is added to the scene. My requirement is to move the camera either left / right side of the scene to view the complete train.

I tried using below code -

```
function onKeyDown(){
     var zdelta = 20;
     switch( event.keyCode ) {
         case 65: // look left
        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + zdelta;
        }
     }
```

But the scene was rotating rather than panning in the left side.

So it will be great help, if anyone shares their idea on this :)

Thanks,
Satheesh K

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate your issue with a live example (https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Right now, it's not really possible to give meaningful feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87, this is the link to my example - https://jsfiddle.net/satheeshKS10/qgcLmyfn/42/

Comment: @Mugen87,
The sample contains multiple rectangles arranged in a queue ( imagine like we have 100 rectangles ), our motive is to move the camera left and right direction to view the left  & right rectangles in the scene.

Comment: @Mugen87, when using OrbitControls.js, the camera moves circularly rather than moving the left or right direction. I have updated the sample code here - https://github.com/SatheeshKS10/ThreeJS-CameraControls and the sample - https://satheeshks10.github.io/ThreeJS-CameraControls/CameraControls.html

Comment: This seems to happen because `OrbitControls` has a focus point defined by its `target` vector. Have you tried to change this vector in the same way you change the camera's position?

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87, I will try that and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `keydown` event listener is definitely the right approach. Try it with this code:

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, cubeObj;

init();
animate();


function init() {

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
 camera.position.z = 400;
 camera.position.y = - 10;
 camera.position.x = 10;

 var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 150, 100 );

 var cubeGeoMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x808080 } );

 cubeObj = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeGeoMaterial );

 cubeObj.position.x = - 70;
 cubeObj.position.y = - 50;
 cubeObj.position.z = 0;
 cubeObj.rotation.x = 0.5;
 scene.add( cubeObj );

 var cubeGeo2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 150, 100 );

 var cubeGeoMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x808080 } );

 var cubeObj2 = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo2, cubeGeoMaterial2 );

 cubeObj2.position.x = 160;
 cubeObj2.position.y = - 50;
 cubeObj2.position.z = - 5;

 cubeObj2.rotation.x = 0.5;

 scene.add( cubeObj2 );

 var cubeGeo3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 150, 100 );

 var cubeGeoMaterial3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x808080 } );

 var cubeObj3 = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo3, cubeGeoMaterial3 );

 cubeObj3.position.x = 440;
 cubeObj3.position.y = - 50;
 cubeObj3.position.z = 0;

 cubeObj3.rotation.x = 0.5;

 scene.add( cubeObj3 );

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
  antialias: true
 } );

 var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
 spotLight.position.set( 100, 1000, 100 );

 spotLight.castShadow = true;

 spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
 spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;

 spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;
 spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
 spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = 30;

 //scene.add( spotLight );

 var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
 scene.add( directionalLight );

 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 renderer.setClearColor( 0xcce0ff );
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

}

function onKeyDown( event ) {

 const step = 5; // world units

 switch ( event.keyCode ) {

  case 37:
   camera.position.x -= step;
   break;

  case 39:
   camera.position.x += step;
   break;

 }

}

function animate() {

 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );

}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks@Mugen87, that did the trick. I added that code snippet to the above fiddle sample, [link] https://jsfiddle.net/satheeshKS10/qgcLmyfn/54/ and it's working fine. 
I need to make some changes to my actual codebase to make it work.

Comment: Also, there is some problem encountered when using the above solution with OrbitControls.js. 
I faced an issue, where the camera moved in a circular way rather than moving in left / right direction, I resolved this by moving out the - orbitControls.update() from animate() method.